# Rails 5 API + Real time notifications

Tags: redis, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api, actioncable

I'm creating a Rails 5 API only and I need to create a real time web notifications.

Is that possible by using ActionCable? Does anyone has an example of Action Cable or any other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a web notification channel that allows you to trigger client-side web notifications when you broadcast to the right streams:

Create the server-side web notifications channel:

```
# app/channels/web_notifications_channel.rb
class WebNotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_for current_user
  end
end
```

Create the client-side web notifications channel subscription:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/cable/subscriptions/web_notifications.coffee
# Client-side which assumes you've already requested
# the right to send web notifications.
App.cable.subscriptions.create "WebNotificationsChannel",
  received: (data) ->
    new Notification data["title"], body: data["body"]
```

Broadcast content to a web notification channel instance from elsewhere in your application:

```
# Somewhere in your app this is called, perhaps from a NewCommentJob
WebNotificationsChannel.broadcast_to(
  current_user,
  title: 'New things!',
  body: 'All the news fit to print'
)
```

The `WebNotificationsChannel.broadcast_to` call places a message in the current subscription adapter's pubsub queue under a separate broadcasting name for each user. For a user with an ID of 1, the broadcasting name would be `web_notifications:1`.